# OpenID Connect log in in with Office 365 and spring security

Tags: azure, spring-security, office365, openid-connect

I need to configure **OpenID Connect** using a **Spring Security** filter to authorize the consumption of my Rest API Web. I found a [Google Login Example](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-openid-connect), but in my case I need it for Office365. I created my app in Azure and I have configured the corresponding properties. When I try to access my REST API it redirects me to the office login and when I enter the correct credentials this exception is thrown:

[image: Image error in console]

Comment: did you manage to get this resolved?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the cause for this particular exception, but generally there is a good tutorial at Microsoft Azure developer pages that explains how to use Spring Boot, Spring Security for authentication at Microsoft Azure Active Directory:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/configure-spring-boot-starter-java-app-with-azure-active-directory

With this implemented you can login at your web application with a Microsoft account.
In section "Add an application registration for your Spring Boot app" at step 2 you can choose whether you (or your app) want to support accounts single tenant, multi tenant or even personal Microsoft accounts (Skype, Xbox, ...).

There are only three two differences (in 08/2020) between tutorial and my working test-application:

1. you've got to set both properties "oauth2AllowImplicitFlow" AND "oauth2AllowIdTokenImplicitFlow" to "true".
2. the property in application.properties seems to be "azure.activedirectory.active-directory-groups" instead of "azure.activedirectory.user-group.allowed-groups"