# Spring Security and Azure: is there a Active Directory group wildcard?

Tags: java, spring-security, azure-active-directory

The tutorial at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/configure-spring-boot-starter-java-app-with-azure-active-directory explains how to set up Spring Security with authentication at Microsoft Azure Active Directory.

Disregarding from two little differences (explained here [OpenID Connect log in in with Office 365 and spring security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43788333/openid-connect-log-in-in-with-office-365-and-spring-security/63517600#63517600) ) this works fine.

In my application.properties there is this property:

```
azure.activedirectory.active-directory-groups=myADUserGroup
```

(Hint: azure.activedirectory.active-directory-groups seems to be the deprecated version of the newer azure.activedirectory.user-group.allowed-groups ...)

I don't want to limit on particular groups. Every user with a valid Microsoft account is OK for my use case.
Leaving the property blank or even deleting the property leads to this exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: One of the User Group Properties must be populated. Please populate azure.activedirectory.user-group.allowed-groups
at com.microsoft.azure.spring.autoconfigure.aad.AADAuthenticationProperties.validateUserGroupProperties(AADAuthenticationProperties.java:148) ~[azure-spring-boot-2.3.1.jar:na]
```

A possible workaround is to enter some arbitrary group name for the property in application.properties:

```
azure.activedirectory.active-directory-groups=some-arbitrary-group-name-doesnt-matter
```

and just do not use `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('[group / role name]')")`.

This works (as long as your app is not interested in the role names) but it does not feel correct.
A) Is there a "right" way to set a wildcard active-directory-group?
B) org.springframework.security.core.Authentication.getAuthorities() seems to deliver only those group names / role names that are entered in that property, so the workaround delivers none (but ROLE_USER). I want to read all the groups / roles at the user. So I ask a second question: How can I get all roles from org.springframework.security.core.Authentication.getAuthorities() without knowing all of them and especially without entering all of them into the "azure.activedirectory.active-directory-groups" property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there is no support for a wildcard for groups at the moment, I built a workaround by ignoring whether the user group is valid or not.

For this I made a copy of com.microsoft.azure.spring.autoconfigure.aad.AzureADGraphClient and commented out this code snippet:

```
.filter(this::isValidUserGroupToGrantAuthority)
```

and I made a copy of com.microsoft.azure.spring.autoconfigure.aad.AADOAuth2UserService with

```
graphClient = new MyAzureADGraphClient(...
```

instead of

```
graphClient = new AzureADGraphClient(...
```

And in the SecurityConfiguration I injected the AAD properties:

```
@Autowired(required = false) private AADAuthenticationProperties aadAuthenticationProperties;
@Autowired(required = false) private ServiceEndpointsProperties serviceEndpointsProps;
```

and called my own AADOAuth2UserService in void configure(HttpSecurity http):

```
EvaAADOAuth2UserService oidcUserService = new EvaAADOAuth2UserService(aadAuthenticationProperties, serviceEndpointsProps);
httpSecurity.oauth2Login().loginPage(LOGIN_URL).permitAll().userInfoEndpoint().oidcUserService(oidcUserService);
```

Answer (score 1):

For now, **it does not support to set a wildcard for azure active directory group**.

You can give you [voice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory) to azure ad feedback and if others have same demand will voteup you. Much vote will promote this feature to be achieve.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a group wildcard, but if [stateless processing](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/master/sdk/spring/azure-spring-boot-starter-active-directory/README.md#authenticate-stateless-apis-using-aad-app-roles) suits your need,

```
azure.activedirectory.active-directory-groups=...
```

may be replaced with

```
azure.activedirectory.session-stateless=true
```

This will activate `AADAppRoleStatelessAuthenticationFilter` instead of `AADAuthenticationFilter`, which doesn't require specifying groups via `azure.activedirectory.active-directory-groups`.
The roles you want to use have to declared in the [application manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/uk-ua/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps)

Comment: Hi Serhii, thanks for that good hint. My context is a Vaadin application that keeps the current state of buttons, input fields and so on at serverside. Server and browser exchange small changes only. So it's stateful.